# Acces type of derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, pool

class derived:**protected** base ==>
int this case all protected and public members  of the base class are protected for the derived one

class derived:**public** base ==>
int this case all protected and public members  of the base class are respectively protected and public for the derived one

in both cases the derived class can access the public and the protected members of the base class, what's the difference ?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance)?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is what other classes can access.

It's a question of what gets exposed as `public` in the end to other classes, not as much as what gets exposed to derived classes.